# Installed 16.04 - No Internet - does not recognize wired connection Killer 1535 card

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, bluetooth

Purchased a Dell Desktop Alienware i7 hex-core R7 Windows 10 computer, which comes with the Killer 1535 wired/wireless Bluetooth card.

Took it home and installed 16.04.

Whilst installing, Ubuntu did not recognize neither my wired connection or the wireless route signal.

After a DVD/CD installation, still there is no Internet recognition.

No online assistance thus far has worked either. [Not even Killer's own link](https://www.killernetworking.com/driver-downloads/kb/faq/1-killer-1535-1525-1435-in-ubuntu-debian).

Results from:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac 
Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network 
Adapter [1a56:1535]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

and from:

```
sudo lshw -C network

 *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:f0:ef:e9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:142 memory:df200000-df3fffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df400000-df43ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

and for:

```
sudo rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Results from:

```
dmesg | grep wlp

[    6.209682] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6.232744] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
```

Results from `dmesg | grep ath`:

```
[    3.749956] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.751082] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.783269] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_hdmi(+) x86_pkg_temp_thermal coretemp nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel(-) aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw ath10k_pci(OE+) gf128mul ath10k_core(OE) glue_helper snd_hda_intel ablk_helper ath(OE) cryptd snd_hda_codec mac80211(OE) snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_pcm snd_rawmidi input_leds cfg80211(OE) compat(OE) snd_seq hci_uart snd_seq_device btusb snd_timer btrtl btbcm btqca snd btintel soundcore bluetooth shpchp 8250_fintek dell_rbtn mac_hid intel_lpss_acpi acpi_pad intel_lpss acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio alx(OE) mdio parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic usbhid nouveau mxm_wmi i2c_algo_bit
[    3.783302]  [<ffffffff81080f62>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[    3.783303]  [<ffffffff810810aa>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[    3.783343]  [<ffffffff818244f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[    3.991764] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:05:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.991794] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-pci-168c:003e:1a56:1535.bin failed with error -2
[    3.991795] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2
[    3.991966] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    3.991968] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    6.138280] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff, 168c:003e:1a56:1535 fallback) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[    6.138283] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: debug 1 debugfs 1 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    6.206557] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[    6.206558] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    6.206560] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    6.206560] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[    6.209682] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
[   11.510695] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable ani by default: -11
[   17.510786] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   22.858862] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   28.858944] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   34.203027] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable ani by default: -11
[   40.202942] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   56.303159] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   62.303428] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   67.647518] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   73.647394] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   89.303814] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   95.303707] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  100.647785] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  106.647901] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  122.300302] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  128.300190] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  133.644309] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  139.644341] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  155.304781] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  161.304698] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  166.648785] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  172.648821] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  188.301255] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  194.301328] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  199.645373] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  205.645483] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
```

Results:

```
Dmesg | grep ath:

[    3.738124] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.739035] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.799010] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_hdmi(+) x86_pkg_temp_thermal coretemp kvm_intel dell_wmi nls_iso8859_1 alienware_wmi sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ath10k_pci(OE+) snd_hda_codec aesni_intel snd_hda_core ath10k_core(OE) snd_hwdep aes_x86_64 ath(OE) lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd mac80211(OE) snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi cfg80211(OE) snd_pcm snd_seq compat(OE) snd_seq_device snd_timer btusb input_leds btrtl snd hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel soundcore bluetooth shpchp 8250_fintek acpi_pad intel_lpss_acpi dell_rbtn intel_lpss mac_hid acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio alx(OE) mdio parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic usbhid nouveau mxm_wmi
[    3.799042]  [<ffffffff81080f62>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[    3.799043]  [<ffffffff810810aa>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[    3.799081]  [<ffffffff818244f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[    3.975922] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:05:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.976060] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-pci-168c:003e:1a56:1535.bin failed with error -2
[    3.976062] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2
[    3.976695] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    3.976697] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    6.122009] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff, 168c:003e:1a56:1535 fallback) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[    6.122011] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: debug 1 debugfs 1 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    6.190281] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[    6.190283] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    6.190284] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    6.190285] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[    6.192748] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
[   11.502529] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable ani by default: -11
[   17.502538] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   22.846529] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   28.846600] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   34.190616] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   40.190640] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   55.302680] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   61.302709] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   66.646748] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   72.646782] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   88.302836] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   94.302858] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   99.646689] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  105.646897] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  121.302949] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  127.302981] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  132.647000] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  138.647005] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  154.303082] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  160.303100] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  165.647116] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  171.647149] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  187.303197] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  193.303229] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  198.647246] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  204.647279] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
```

Results for:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version

dpkg-query: error: --status needs a valid package name but 'linux=firmware' is not: illegal package name in specifier 'linux=firmware': character '=' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters '-+._')

Use --help for help about querying packages.
```

and for:

```
ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0

board-2.bin  firmware-4.bin  notice_ath10k_firmware-4.txt
board.bin    firmware-6.bin  notice_ath10k_firmware-6.txt
```

Comment: Is your wireless indeed an *ath10k_pci* device? Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to add the result.

Comment: At least with the wireless, you seem to be all good! Does it scan? `sudo iwlist scan` Just tell us if it sees networks. When you click the Network Manager icon, do you see the scanned networks? https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2014/07/ubuntu-networkmanager-menu-100360176-large.png

Comment: Results: wlp5s0 Interface doesn't support scanning: network is down; lo Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: Sorry. It's a desktop.

Comment: We wonder why the network is down. Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep wlp` As you have no way to copy and paste the result, we'll trust you to look for and post anything that you think might be extraordinary.

Comment: When I click on the Internet icon at top right, it says that device is not ready. What about the output from: lshw -C network, says, *-network DISABLED, for the wireless interface.

Comment: DISABLED usually means that the hardware switch on a laptop is set to disable the wireless radio. However, you have a desktop, although, like many mini PCs, NUCs, etc., it was built with laptop parts. Any clues in dmesg as I requested?

Comment: Using a thumb-drive I can copy&paste: dmesg | grep wlp

[    6.209682] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6.232744] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready

Comment: No clues there. How about: `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: Too long for the comments so I edited my post above.

Comment: Fresh download and install solved the problem. Thanks for all your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fresh download and install solved the problem.

My computer is the latest version Dell i7 Aurora R7 with a Killer 1535 ethernet card (wired/wireless/bluetooth). An one year old version did not work. However, a fresh download and install did the trick!!

Thanks for all your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

In your dmesg we see:

> ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

This is evidently a firmware bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1520343

Notice that the bug report specifically mentions your exact device: 168c:003e.

Let’s upgrade the firmware to see if it helps. Since you do not have any internet on this device, download this file on some other computer, transfer it on a USB key and drag and drop it to the desktop of the subject machine: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.1_all.deb

Now, in a terminal:

```
cd Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

Comment: Results: sudo dkg -i linux*.deb , sudo: dkg: command not found .

Comment: Realized that the dkg was missing the letter 'p' . Corrected the error and retried with no success. Nothing changed other than the updated file.

Comment: Question: Thinking of all the results, what one line of code would cause a cascade of issues preventing Ubuntu from seeing and using the wired Ethernet?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Corrected. Are the dmesg errors the same? We haven't begun the ethernet yet and I'm not sure what 'line of code' you have in mind. If you wish to abandon the wireless (I don't) and try the ethernet, please start a new question and include: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200`

Comment: Results: lspci -nnk | grep 0200, 06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [1969.eb1] ( rev 10). My comment above was just a thought. Have no particular line of code in mind. dmesg coming. Thanks

Comment: Posted above the results for: demsg... after the updating. Looks to me no change.

Comment: I am quite mystified by: "could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2" Please repeat the process with this file and reboot: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.2_all.deb

Comment: I repeated the process... still no Internet. The "dmesg | grep ath " reads the same as above. No change. Just want to say, thank you for trouble shooting this issue. BTW: I watched it update the file.

Comment: What is the result of: `sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version` and also: `ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0` ?

Comment: The results: sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version, dpkg-query: error: --status needs a valid package name but 'linux=firmware' is not: illegal package name in specifier 'linux=firmware': character '=' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters '-+._')

Use --help for help about querying packages. 
AND FOR: 
ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0, 
board-2.bin  firmware-4.bin  notice_ath10k_firmware-4.txt
board.bin    firmware-6.bin  notice_ath10k_firmware-6.txt

Comment: Should I try installing an older version such as 14.04?

Comment: It isn't linux=firmware; it is linux-firmware.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I did type it incorrectly. Result is: Version: 1.169.2

Comment: FYI. I've taken the wifi from my other PC that works with 14.04 installed and plugged it into the i7 Dell Alienware Auraro R7 PC; it never even noticed that it was plugged in. So I decided to try installing 14.04 instead. However, during the installation the Internet still was not working--so I stopped the installation. I found out that I can reset the default software back to w10. After that I should return the computer for a more Ubuntu friendly machine--no windows. BTW, Killer never returned my email asking for assistance from three days ago. Thanks for all your efforts! :)

Comment: Fresh download and install solved the problem. Thanks for all your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also on 16.04 and gave the same care on an AW17R3:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Over the last couple of days a new driver was pushed into 16.04 and 17.10 so hopefully soon if you get a brand new install Live USB it will work fine. From the [bug report](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash/161000f4b13cbedf):

> Hi, I do confrirm that linux-firmware 1.157.16 indeed fixes this
>   problem, and it doesn't introduce any regression to previous version.
>   My laptop is a Dell XPS, which includes a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174
>   Wireless Network Adapter.
>
> I am on kernel 4.13.0-32 and by using firmware ver
>   WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1 api 6, I can check that the connection
>   lasts and it can performs smoothly for some hours now (when it was
>   dropping silently after 10/15 minutes before).

However this fix is in ***proposed*** section: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/proposed/linux-firmware

I'm not sure how long until it gets into the daily build.

FTR I have a separate Killer Wired card which I use day to day so never relied on the WiFi Card above. My wired card:

```
3b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Device [0707:2400]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
```

I think you should take an Cat 5e cable (blue Ethernet with RJ-45 ends)  and plug it in between your laptop and the router. Hopefully you have a separate Ethernet card and it's not a combined Wired/Wireless/Bluetooth card like you were led to believe.

Comment: His ethernet is unclaimed meaning no driver. It won't work with a CAT5e cable at all.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks for pointing that out. Mine worked out of the box. In fact it's worked on every laptop out of the box.

Comment: I'm hoping we can coax the wireless to life and use it to fix the ethernet.

Comment: Sorry, it's a desktop

Comment: @todd Sorry I missed that part. So used to Alienware laptops. Guess that's how they merged Wifi+Ethernet on the same PCIe card.

Comment: Here's what I purchased: https://www.bestbuy.com/site/alienware-aurora-r6-desktop-intel-core-i7-16gb-memory-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1070-1tb-hard-drive-intel-optane-memory-epic-silver/6124573.p?skuId=6124573&cmp=RMX&extStoreId=398&ref=212&loc=1&ksid=3c11c334-5742-48fa-a1ce-fb1248963507&ksprof_id=8&ksaffcode=pg199028&ksdevice=c&lsft=ref:212,loc:2

Comment: Ethernet: Killer wireless and wired networking
Killer Game Networking LAN also lets you plug into wired 10/100/1000 networks.

Comment: @todd Mine also has Killer Wireless and Killer Wired only they are on two separate parts of the laptop. Strangely though everything I have worked out of the box. I did use Windows 10 to download and install all the Dell drivers first before installing Ubuntu though. Have you updated your drivers in Windows 10 from the Dell web site?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 16.04 over Win10

Comment: @todd Too late now but I recommend keeping W10 and installing Ubuntu along side it. You can always use your license key burned into your motherboard to reinstall W10 and get things working there first before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Would that have allowed Ubuntu to access the Internet?

Comment: @todd Updating the Dell firware/BIOS drivers in Windows often updates the drivers for Ubuntu as well. Compare my specs to yours and consider the fact both my Killers work like a charm.

Comment: Fresh download and install solved the problem. Thanks for all your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to enable the ethernet device with

```
sudo modprobe alx
echo '1969 e0b1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/alx/new_id
```

Then see if ethernet works

Comment: Sorry, but none of these idea solved the problem. However, I did solve it and wanted to let everyone know what solved it. I downloaded fresh Ubuntu files, imaged it on a thumb drive and installed it. It worked! Since my computer is the latest version on the market Dell i7 with Killer 1535 ethernet card, it must also require the latest version of Ubuntu.